# How do I create a base-36 identity in SQL Server?

Tags: sql

For example, KF12OI as seen on airline websites.

What do I need to do in order to use base-36 primary keys in SQL Server 2008? I've researched this and all indications are it cannot be done out of the box.

I thought about creating an identity column and then having a second column the gets updated by trigger. The second column contains the actual primary key / ID of the row.

The other part of this question is how can I eliminate vowels from usage? So, this is actually base-26, not 36, using numbers 0-9 and all letters except vowels?

Comment: Is there any reason the **DATA** can't be a `Bigint IDENTITY` but you expose the base26 via a function?

Comment: @JNK - I'd like to make the shortened ID (base-36) the PK and use it for FKs. I think it would just be easier when troubleshooting / developing against it.

Comment: potential downside of Base36: words appearing in your unique ID's.  "Hello John, you have been confirmed for flight DEATH666, enjoy your flight!"

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, SQL Server does not offer anything like this out of the box.  The only way I have seen this done is using the trigger method that you described.  Unless you use a GUID I do not think there is a way to get an autogenerated alphanumeric identity column.