# Custom SQL Unique Idenifier using 34 Bit

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm working in a database where they wanted to use 0-Z for their ID's. The result is a rather complex system to work with when I need to generate records in bulk.

I thought about creating a table with every possible ID, but that would be astronomically huge. 24^10 possible ID's.

The issue I have is that I need a way to programmatically generate the next number. At current, no one remembers how the ID's are generated.

Is there a way to generate your next ID in SQL when you have custom counting like this?

Comment: There is no way to do something in any language if "no one remembers how the IDs are generated".  You gotta know what you are doing before you start.

Comment: +1 on the above comment, if they're bigints converted to base 36 that's easy enough, but if you don't know what the logic is, you can't re-implement it.

Comment: The logic is easy, but reproducing it is hard. 

YOu have a 10 character ID. Everytime a position reaches Z, the next position to the left increments and all positions to the right reset to zero. 

Example:
Current: 000000000Z  Next: 0000000010
Current: 000000000A  Next: 000000000B
Current: 00000ZZZZZ  Next: 0000100000

Just for a few examples.

Comment: Sounds like just a base 36 number? If that's the case, then you know exactly how it's generated, don't you? Seems like it would be straight-forward to create a NextID function that takes a string as a parameter, decodes it into a bigint value, adds one, then re-encodes as a base-36 string.

Comment: The reliable solution is to create a `BigInt` `identity` column and a computed column that converts the `BigInt` to base-36 for display. Like any identity column, there may be missing values (e.g. when a transaction is rolled back) but never duplicates. Nice comments on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070712/how-do-i-create-a-base-36-identity-in-sql-server) question. And [this](https://gist.github.com/Plutor/2511071) old solution at github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method, as recommended above, is to use a `BIGINT` value to store the number, and convert it into a code. Here is a sample proc that will convert a number to a code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetCardCode
    @CardValue bigint
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @cardCode varchar(10) = '',
        @LetterList varchar(36) = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

    DECLARE @i int,
        @ptr int,
        @mod int

    SET @i = 10
    WHILE @i > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @ptr = @CardValue % 36 + 1
        SET @cardCode = SUBSTRING(@LetterList, @ptr, 1) + @cardCode
        SET @CardValue = (@CardValue - (@ptr - 1) ) / 36
        SET @i = @i - 1
    END
    SELECT @cardCode
END
```

If you call this function with a card value parameter of `6912301486`, it will return a code of `00036BELYM`.

This procedure is faster than you might worry about. I generated a thousand sequential codes in about 3/10ths of a second.  And, if nothing else, it should put you on the correct path to finding a solution that you can work with.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't tried yours, but I was able to figure it out. I'll check out what you did as you went about things a different way. It might even be faster than what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

So, I did figure it out. It took some time, but here we go.

```
declare     @validCharacters nvarchar(max),
            @currentValidCharacter int,
            @tableName nvarchar(max),
            @lastOID nvarchar(10),
            @newOID nvarchar(10),
            @currentCharacter nvarchar(1),
            @characterPosition int,
            @sqlQuery nvarchar(max),
            @tableCount int



set @tableName = 'MyTable'
set @validCharacters = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
set @currentCharacter = '0'
set @characterPosition = 10 

set @sqlQuery = 'select top(1) @lastOID = OID from ' + @tableName + ' order by OID desc'
    exec sp_executesql @sqlQuery, N'@lastOID nvarchar(10) OUTPUT',@lastOID = @lastOID OUTPUT


set @sqlQuery = 'select @tableCount = count(*) from ' + @tableName 
    exec sp_executesql @sqlQuery, N'@tableCount int OUTPUT',@tableCount = @tableCount OUTPUT

if @tableCount > 0
    BEGIN

        while 1=1
            BEGIN
                set @currentCharacter = substring(@lastOID,@characterPosition,1)
                print 'TEST:' + char(9) + @currentCharacter + char(9) + @lastOID

                if @currentCharacter <> 'Z'
                    BEGIN
                        set @currentValidCharacter = patindex('%' + @currentCharacter + '%',@validCharacters)
                        set @currentCharacter = SUBSTRING(@validCharacters,@currentValidCharacter+1,1)
                        set @newOID = stuff(@lastOID,@characterPosition,1,@currentCharacter)
                        print 'New:' + char(9) + @currentCharacter + char(9) + @newOID
                        break               

                    END
                ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        set @currentCharacter = '0'
                        set @newOID = stuff(@lastOID,@characterPosition,1,@currentCharacter)
                        set @characterPosition -= 1             
                        print 'New:' + char(9) + @currentCharacter + char(9) + @newOID

                    END




            END

    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        set @newOID = '0000000000'
    END


print 'Generated OID:' + char(9) + @newOID
```

This will pull the last ID from a table, then generate the next ID. I set some dummy ID's up for testing. With Z00ZZZZZZZ, it generated Z010000000.

So, it's a little different than what Vergil recommended, but it's working well. I just need to wrap this around as a function, then I can use it in longer scripts.

Hope someone out there finds this useful.