# Increment from 1-9 then A-Z in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a unique identifier that is 11 characters long. What I want to do is start out with 00000000001 go to 00000000009 then start with 0000000000A to 0000000000Z after I hit Z then I would use the next column 00000000011 to 00000000019 then 0000000001A to 000000000001Z. How would I go about accomplishing this? I know how to increment letters and numbers separately but how would I put this all together?

Comment: Where do you store this sequence?

Comment: Why in the world do you want to do this? There are so many major problems with this. You have issues of concurrency. You have to worry about all sorts of words you don't want. Why not just use an identity or a uniqueidentifier and be done with it?

Comment: store an int then if you really need to convert to base 36 for an ordinality of 1..Z, 10..1Z,

Comment: You're just Base 36 encoding an integer.  Your question is basically the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070712/how-do-i-create-a-base-36-identity-in-sql-server), though that one has no answer, either.  Searching for "base 36 sql server" gives me lots of potential leads, however.

Comment: You can follow this post, option 3 (base X encoding) http://www.sqlteam.com/article/custom-auto-generated-sequences-with-sql-server

Comment: McNets the sequence will be stored in a table the last value will be looked up. and the next one generated based on the last value.

Comment: Your method of storing the value and getting the next one is the concurrency issue I was mentioning. What happens when two or more people are trying to get the next value at the same time? You run the risk of providing the same "next value" to multiple requests. You can overcome that but you have to be careful and use some locking hints.

Comment: Don't you want to go from `0000Z` to `00010` instead of `00011`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alex K. says, use an `IDENTITY(1,1)` for your primary key in your table and calculate the value of your crazy base 36 value using something like this:

```
declare @Val BIGINT

    set @val = 45643

    DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(9) = ''


    WHILE (@Val > 0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Result = CHAR(@Val % 36 + CASE WHEN @Val % 36 < 10 THEN 48 ELSE 55 END) + @Result,
               @Val = FLOOR(@Val/36)
    END

    select right('00000000000' + @Result, 11)
```

Code from here: https://gist.github.com/Plutor/2511071

Alternatively, you can generate the values using something like this:

```
with a as (
        select  i
        from    (values('0'),('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5'),('6'),('7'),('8'),('9'),('A'),('B'),('C')) v(i)
)
select  a1.i + a2.i + a3.i + a4.i Value,
        row_number() over(order by a1.i + a2.i + a3.i + a4.i) rn
from    a a1, a a2, a a3, a a4
```

Answer (score 0):

I happen to have a function for base 35 encoding. Shouldn't be too difficult to adopt it for base 36:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('DCA.dxConvert_From_Decimal_To_35Base') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP FUNCTION [DCA].[dxConvert_From_Decimal_To_35Base]
END
GO

CREATE FUNCTION DCA.dxConvert_From_Decimal_To_35Base(@DECIMAL_NUMBER INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MOD INT
    DECLARE @TEMP_VALUE VARCHAR(20) 
    DECLARE @BASE_DIGITS VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @BASE INT

    SET @BASE = 35
    SET @TEMP_VALUE = ''
    SET @BASE_DIGITS = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ'

    IF @DECIMAL_NUMBER = 0 
    BEGIN --0 STAYS 0
        RETURN 0
    END 

    WHILE @DECIMAL_NUMBER <> 0
    BEGIN
        SET @MOD = @DECIMAL_NUMBER % @BASE
        SET @TEMP_VALUE = SUBSTRING(@BASE_DIGITS, @MOD + 1 ,  1) + @TEMP_VALUE
        SET @DECIMAL_NUMBER = @DECIMAL_NUMBER / @BASE
    END 

    RETURN @TEMP_VALUE
END
```

Test case:

```
SELECT  SV.number, dca.dxConvert_From_Decimal_To_35Base(SV.number)
FROM    master..spt_values AS SV
WHERE   SV.type = 'P'
```

Results in:

```
+--------+------------------+
| number | (No column name) |
+--------+------------------+
|      0 | 0                |
|      1 | 1                |
|      2 | 2                |
|      3 | 3                |
|      4 | 4                |
|      5 | 5                |
|      6 | 6                |
|      7 | 7                |
|      8 | 8                |
|      9 | 9                |
|     10 | A                |
|     11 | B                |
|     12 | C                |
|     13 | D                |
|     14 | E                |
|     15 | F                |
|     16 | G                |
|     17 | H                |
|     18 | I                |
|     19 | J                |
|     20 | K                |
|     21 | L                |
|     22 | M                |
|     23 | N                |
|     24 | P                |
|     25 | Q                |
|     26 | R                |
|     27 | S                |
|     28 | T                |
|     29 | U                |
|     30 | V                |
|     31 | W                |
|     32 | X                |
|     33 | Y                |
|     34 | Z                |
|     35 | 10               |
|     36 | 11               |
|     37 | 12               |
+--------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert an integer to hexadecimal and then add '000...'

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (value VARCHAR(11));

DECLARE @seq int;
SET @seq = 0;

WHILE @seq < 100
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @t VALUES
    (
        RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 11) + sys.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, @seq, 1, 0), 11)
    );
    SET @seq += 1;

END

SELECT * FROM @t;
```

> ```
> | value       |
> | :---------- |
> | 00000000000 |
> | 00000000001 |
> | 00000000002 |
> | 00000000003 |
> | 00000000004 |
> | 00000000005 |
> | 00000000006 |
> | 00000000007 |
> | 00000000008 |
> | 00000000009 |
> | 0000000000a |
> | 0000000000b |
> | 0000000000c |
> | 0000000000d |
> | 0000000000e |
> | 0000000000f |
> | 00000000010 |
> | 00000000011 |
> | 00000000012 |
> | 00000000013 |
> | 00000000014 |
> | 00000000015 |
> | 00000000016 |
> | 00000000017 |
> | 00000000018 |
> | 00000000019 |
> | 0000000001a |
> | 0000000001b |
> | 0000000001c |
> | 0000000001d |
> | 0000000001e |
> | 0000000001f |
> | 00000000020 |
> | 00000000021 |
> | 00000000022 |
> | 00000000023 |
> | 00000000024 |
> | 00000000025 |
> | 00000000026 |
> | 00000000027 |
> | 00000000028 |
> | 00000000029 |
> | 0000000002a |
> | 0000000002b |
> | 0000000002c |
> | 0000000002d |
> | 0000000002e |
> | 0000000002f |
> | 00000000030 |
> | 00000000031 |
> | 00000000032 |
> | 00000000033 |
> | 00000000034 |
> | 00000000035 |
> | 00000000036 |
> | 00000000037 |
> | 00000000038 |
> | 00000000039 |
> | 0000000003a |
> | 0000000003b |
> | 0000000003c |
> | 0000000003d |
> | 0000000003e |
> | 0000000003f |
> | 00000000040 |
> | 00000000041 |
> | 00000000042 |
> | 00000000043 |
> | 00000000044 |
> | 00000000045 |
> | 00000000046 |
> | 00000000047 |
> | 00000000048 |
> | 00000000049 |
> | 0000000004a |
> | 0000000004b |
> | 0000000004c |
> | 0000000004d |
> | 0000000004e |
> | 0000000004f |
> | 00000000050 |
> | 00000000051 |
> | 00000000052 |
> | 00000000053 |
> | 00000000054 |
> | 00000000055 |
> | 00000000056 |
> | 00000000057 |
> | 00000000058 |
> | 00000000059 |
> | 0000000005a |
> | 0000000005b |
> | 0000000005c |
> | 0000000005d |
> | 0000000005e |
> | 0000000005f |
> | 00000000060 |
> | 00000000061 |
> | 00000000062 |
> | 00000000063 |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=858b6516c3e3538bfcae261f40d019b9)*

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to go with hex then can use a computed column

```
USE [Test]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[hexRep]    Script Date: 4/11/2018 9:52:44 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[hexRep](
    [iden] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [hex]  AS (CONVERT([char](8),CONVERT([varbinary](8),[iden]),(2))),
    [val] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```